# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' when accessing list?

Tags: python

Just a little foreword here that I am very, very new to Python, I've only started learning when I started my current project:

I am currently writing a reddit bot which searches through comments in a certain subreddit. It picks up comments with the prefix `@`. After it does that, I want it to search through a text file and compare it with the word that comes after `@` to see whether said word is in the text file. If it comes out true, the bot will post a reply to said comment with relevant information.

My problem here is that when I run my program, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 46, in <module>
        name_hyphen = searchObjectWithHyphen.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Then the program terminates itself. I'm very sure it has to do with the `if name in monsterList` or `if name_hyphen in monsterList` line or the variables `name` or `name_hyphen` with the search objects in them, because without those lines the program runs fine (which means my search objects do *not* return `none`.)

What am I missing here?

**[Here is my code](https://gist.github.com/xozzo/9850318). I have also checked that the list contains all the keywords in the text file that I have. Note: the keywords in my text file are separated by new lines**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message always means the same thing. You are trying to access an attribute on the `None` object. In this case

```
searchObjectWithHyphen
```

is `None`. Check the code that assigns `searchObjectWithHyphen` to work out why it is `None`. Most likely you made a mistake earlier in the code. If it is normal that `searchObjectWithHyphen` could be `None` then you need special case treatment:

```
if searchObjectWithHyphen is None:
    ....
```

I don't want to try to do the detailed specific debugging for you. Not least because you did not include the code in the question. But more because the real opportunity for you here is to learn **how** to debug this class of problems.

Comment: To be fair, the OP __did__ provide a link to the code along with specific line references

Comment: @sshashank124 A link to some off site pastebin. SO accepts code. I don't feel motivated to dig around offsite when code can be posted here. Anyway, my main point is to try to teach what the error means rather than the specific cause here.

Comment: True. You do have a point. Much easier to deal with the question all on one page

Comment: After reading your answer, I looked at my code again and found the issue: I've declared a variable `name` with a group from `searchObject` before checking that `searchObject` is `True`. Thank you for your input! I also appreciate that you didn't spoonfeed the answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `regex` search for with hyphens is returning NoneType in this line:
`searchObjectWithHyphen = re.search(patternWithHyphen, comment.body, re.IGNORECASE)`

This is because in your pattern:

`patternWithHyphen = '@' + '(\w+(?:-\w+)+)'`

you have to escape your hyphen as well as follows:

`patternWithHyphen = '@' + '(\w+(?:\-\w+)+)'`

Please let me know if that works. Hope that helps

Comment: Nope, this wasn't it. I've tested the regex patterns, they both work fine. :)

Comment: @Xozzo The Python interpreter begs to differ

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just tested the regex both with and without escaping the hyphen, and they both work. Must be some loophole there. Anyway, I just went through some regex docs and realized why it needs to be escaped. Thank you sshashank for pointing it out!